# Issue with SDK 33-Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: android

Trying to update Android sdk version to 33 in our old Android project. while running in the OS-v13 emulator we getting a crash with the below error.

We are not using **PendingIntent** in our project and the **PendingIntent** only available in the files related to SDK 33.

Also tried using `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'` but still the error is not getting resolved.

Failed to deliver response. - Sdk Version: 7.1.0
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles. at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:401) at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:671) at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:658) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:10) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:16) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:74) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.b(Unknown Source:7) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.i.a(Unknown Source:82) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c.c.a(Unknown Source:107) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c.c$b.onReceive(Unknown Source:88) at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313) at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)`

We are facing this error only when update to SDK 33.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have some packages or SDK that calls or depends on pending intent

```
android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:658) at 
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a
```

You can update your MarketingCloud Mobile Push SDK v8.0.0 that supports Android 12

[Please check out this link for reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355238/marketing-cloud-android-sdk-7-4-1-crashes-when-targeting-android-12)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was using MarketingCloud v7.x.x and now updating to v8.0.7 resolved this issue